Бот неожиданно перестал отвечать на сообщения
import telebot
from telebot import types

token = ''
#Создаем экземпляр бота
bot=telebot.TeleBot(token)
#Реакция на команду start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
#функция отправки сообщения при команде start
def start_message(message):
  #Создаем Keyboard-кнопки с видами зп
  keyboard_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
  btn_today = types.KeyboardButton('СПС')
  btn_tomorrow = types.KeyboardButton('/СПФ')
  keyboard_markup.add(btn_today, btn_tomorrow)
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здравствтйте, этот бот может расчитать зарплату на руки', reply_markup=keyboard_markup)
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'СПС' )
def req(message):
  if message.text == 'СПС':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите оклад')
  elif message.text != 'Введите оклад':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'pnhrtr')


Ты проверяешь message.text 2 раза:
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'СПС' )

и
if message.text == 'СПС':

Можешь хендлер просто сделать
@bot.message_handler()
def req(message):

И уже в функции проверять условиями
